# How to enabled cadvisor for kubelet 1.13?

Tags: kubernetes

How to enabled cadvisor for kubelet 1.13?

I want to cadvisor monitor containers in a pod.
Somebody say you should enabled

```
kubelet --cadvisor-port=4194
```

but my kubelet version is 1.13 not have the `--cadvisor` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, kubelet version is 1.13 doesn't have the --cadvisor parameter.

Indeed, the [ChangeLog-1.12](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.12.md) says that:

> The formerly publicly-available cAdvisor web UI that the kubelet started using --cadvisor-port has been entirely removed in 1.12. The recommended way to run cAdvisor if you still need it, is via a DaemonSet [#65707](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/65707)

From the latest ChangeLogs you can see that the cAdvisor is still there - it's just the flag to the kubelet that has been [deprecated](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/65707/commits/5feab863291f2c9f55bee244d09329d819545f4e).

Despite its UI has been deprecated it is still possible to monitor your containers via Prometheus.

There is a good ["How To"](https://github.com/veerendra2/prometheus-k8s-monitoring) resource about K8s monitoring that explains how to run it via DaemonSet.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is always enabled, however the UI was removed so it is no longer available. It is recommended that you use tools like Prometheus and Grafana to visualize the metrics data, however you can also deploy cAdvisor independently of the kubelet if you prefer.