# Has cAdvisor Web UI been deprecated

Tags: kubernetes, cadvisor

There seems be be mixed information and I couldn't find any official
source to confirm this.

From the kubernetes
[changelog](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.12.md),
it seems that cAdvisor web UI which has been available via kubelet has been deprecated:

```
The formerly publicly-available cAdvisor web UI that the kubelet started using --cadvisor-port has been entirely removed in 1.12. The recommended way to run cAdvisor if you still need it, is via a DaemonSet.
```

But this [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60190769/1651941) indicates that UI itself has been deprecated:

```
Despite its UI has been deprecated it is still possible to monitor your containers via Prometheus.
```

From looking at the official [documentation](https://github.com/google/cadvisor/blob/master/docs/web.md), I find no such information.

So my questions is:

- Has the cAdvisor Web UI itself has been deprecated ? (I'm aware that the interface via kubelet option --cadvisor-port is deprecated. But the option being deprecated is different than if the Web UI itself is deprecated)
- If it is deprecated, is there any offical source on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like web ui itself is deprecated.

It's only been removed from kubelet, that's all. It means that the web ui won't be a part of a kubelet anymore.

You can still use it if you want by deploying cAdvisor as separate application.